# PostConstruct doesn't work with session scoped

Tags: jsf, postconstruct, session-scope

I'am using primefaces in a jsf application. I make an update to datalist. That's fine but on persisting data on database the list does not refresh after updating.
I have used @post construct to initially data. But it seems that it is not called.

```
 <p:commandButton value="Validate" action="#{manageUrlSiteTestBean.validate()}" />
```

This is the backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ManageUrlSiteTestBean implements Serializable{
    public String validate(){
        local.updateUrlSite(siteweb);
        form=false;
        siteweb=new SiteWebImpose() ;
        init();
        return null;

    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        setSitewebs(local.listerUrlSiteTests());
    }}
```

Comment: A `@PostConstruct` method in a session scoped managed bean is invoked only once when the associated session is created. If you need, "*refresh after updating*", then you will need a narrower scoped managed bean or trigger the routine performing the task of updating  yourself manually whenever an update is made.

Comment: Please add your `<p:datalist ..` to the question.